# editing PDF to add page number | VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to modify the pdf to add the page number and I cannot find why the variable "cb" is empty.
you can see error on the screen below

```
Error on the screen : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
```

[image]

Comment: You could try adding `New` to the line where you declare `cb`: `Dim cb As New ...`

Comment: I tried but it displays an error

Comment: Screen shot? Really?

Comment: It was at the beginning, I had not read many other posts so I did not know that it was not necessary to put a screen but I put the code of the correction below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found how to edit pdf and add pages number, here is my code for those who need it.

I copy a file, I count the number of pages, in a while loop I display the number of pages (1/3) then I import the page on which I wanted to add the number of pages.

```
 Public Sub ModifPDF(ByVal annee As Integer, ByVal mois As Integer, ByVal nomFichier As String, ByVal sourceFileList As String)
            Dim Col1 As PdfPCell
            Dim Col2 As PdfPCell
            Dim Font1 As New Font(FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 1, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL))
            Dim Font8 As New Font(FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL))
            Dim Vide As PdfPCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase("")) With {
                    .Border = 0
                }
    
            Dim reader As New PdfReader(sourceFileList)
            Dim sourceFilePageCount As Integer = reader.NumberOfPages
    
            Dim doc As New Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(sourceFileList, "C:\test")
            Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream("C:\test", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
            doc.Open()
    
            Dim contentByte As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
    
            Dim pageIndex As Integer = 0
            While pageIndex < sourceFilePageCount
                pageIndex = pageIndex + 1
    
                doc.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSize(pageIndex))
    
                Dim TableNota As PdfPTable = New PdfPTable(2)
                Dim widthsNota As Single() = New Single() {19.7F, 1.5F}
                TableNota.WidthPercentage = 97
                TableNota.SetWidths(widthsNota)
    
    
                Col1 = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(" ", Font8)) With {
                .Border = 0
            }
                TableNota.AddCell(Col1)
                Col2 = New PdfPCell(New Phrase("page " & pageIndex & "/" & sourceFilePageCount & "", Font8)) With {
                .Border = 0
            }
                TableNota.AddCell(Col2)
                TableNota.AddCell(Vide)
    
                doc.Add(TableNota)
    
                Dim page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pageIndex)
                Dim rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(pageIndex)
    
                If rotation.Equals(90) Then
                    contentByte.AddTemplate(page, 0, -0.1F, 1.0F, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex).Height)
                Else
                    contentByte.AddTemplate(page, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, 0)
                End If
    
                doc.NewPage()
    
            End While
    
            doc.Close()
    
        End Sub
```